# C++ static analysis: finding all places where some member function is called

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to find all calls to a member function of some particular class. Besides finding the calls, I am also interested in having the arguments passed to each call. For example, after analyzing this code:

```
anyfile.cpp:
myobject.AFunction("string", 0);

otherfile.cpp:
otherobject.AFunction("anystring", aValue);
```

I would expect some output like:

```
AFunction called in file "anyfile.cpp" with arguments "string" and 0
AFunction called in file "otherfile.cpp" with arguments "anystring" and aValue=5
...
```

I thought of parsing all source code using regexps, but of course that wouldn't work, since AFunction may appear in other classes, and that wouldn't get me the value of the variables used as arguments.

I think that I may need some kind of static analysis tool, I am also interested in calls that never (or very rarely) happen. I.e., running the program and trying to generate some log wouldn't be a solution. There are hundreds of places where the method is called, but the software rarely gets to those calls (or maybe never).

Comment: If you are using an eclipse based IDE, you can highlight the method and use Ctrl+Shift+G.  To find all instances of the text of the method, use Ctrl+Alt+G

Comment: Not a solution, as I say, there are thousands of calls and I need the data for later processing.

Comment: It's impossible to gather such info statically, unless it is sufficient for you to gather only constant arguments passed to non-template functions. In that case you can play with `gcc` debugging flags such as `-fdump-tree-cfg`

Comment: All arguments are constant, but unfortunately they may not be declared as constant variables.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you try out cscope. It builds a database file so you don't have to re-build the symbol tables and such each time you run it. With some vim scripting you could even manage to get it to output to a file I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try out Doxygen. It can build documentation for caller and callees.